# powershell command to list all users, their home directories + sizes

Tags: powershell, home-directory

I need a script or command that would list all users on a computer plus their home directories and sizes of their home directories. I can do it only for users are looged in. I also managed to get a list of all users :

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | Select-Object @{n='UserName'
e={$_.Name}}
```

but I don't know how to get home dir, plus size from that list.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read a [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx) about getting folder size?

Comment: yes i know how to get a folder size but only for one user. what i don't know is how to connect it together, to get home dir and home dir size for all users in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a powershell loop that outputs objects with the properties you are looking for (Name, LocalPath, FolderSize), formatted as a table.  This combines a few techniques to get the values you are looking for.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile | % { 
    try {
        $out = new-object psobject
        $out | Add-Member noteproperty Name (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.SID)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
        $out | Add-Member noteproperty LocalPath $_.LocalPath
        $out | Add-Member noteproperty FolderSize ("{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.LocalPath | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).sum / 1MB) + " MB")
        $out
    } catch {}
} | Format-Table
```

Comment: This works only with **PowerShell <=5.x** and must be executed as *Administrator*. `Get-WmiObject` has been deprecated in **PowerShell Core** in favor of `Get-CimInstance`. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4766